# Online website - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql

this is the message that i can see on the **online** website that I'm trying to edit.. I've seen some post about this problem on a local website but I don't know how to solve the problem on an online website. I premise that I'm not too good in databases stuff.. what's the problem? how can I solve it? thx in advance for any answer!

Comment: Probably MySQL server is down. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html or wrong configuration of the script, as MySQL can be running on another host.

Comment: What do you mean by "online website that I'm trying to edit"? How are you editing it? Do you mean that it's hosted on some service (i.e., not on your personal computer)?

Comment: Likely has to be proxied. On my developer site I have to use a specific command (mysql-ctl cli) as standard commands don't work. Check your host's documentation.

Comment: yes, is not on my personal computer.. I said "trying to edit" because is an old website done by someone else that I need to update.. the only thing I know is that everything was going well until I added a row inside the db

Answer (score 0):

Either the mysql.sock file isn't in /var/lib/mysql/, or the mysql-server isn't running or there is no mysql-server on this server. You should check out your (Web)-Control-Panel, your logindata (and the host) should be written somewhere.